# Подскажите почему у блока не работает margin-bottom?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Подскажите почему у блока `triangle` не работает `margin-bottom`? который 1

```css
#pictures {
  text-align: center;
  width: 1366px;
  height: 385px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#tv {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 193px;
}

.pictureone {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.picturetwo {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#containerfortv {
  margin-left: 70px;
  width: 111px;
  height: 112px;
  display: block;
}

#containerfortv:hover>.pictureone {
  display: none;
}

#containerfortv:hover>.picturetwo {
  display: block;
}

#pencil {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 305px;
  max-height: 300px;
  margin: 77px auto 0;
}

#containerforpencil {
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  width: 115px;
  height: 118px;
  display: block;
}

#containerforpencil:hover>.pictureone {
  display: none;
}

#containerforpencil:hover>.picturetwo {
  display: inline-block;
}

#mountains {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 305px;
  max-height: 300px;
  margin-left: 46px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#containerformountains {
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  width: 128px;
  height: 112px;
  display: block;
}

#containerformountains:hover>.pictureone {
  display: none;
}

#containerformountains:hover>.picturetwo {
  display: inline-block;
}

#clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

#triangleup {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 80px solid green;
}

#triangle {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section id="pictures">
  <div id="tv">
    <div id="containerfortv">
      <img class="pictureone" src="https://b.radikal.ru/b39/1801/6a/339592a851eb.png">
      <img class="picturetwo" src="https://b.radikal.ru/b39/1801/6a/339592a851eb.png">
    </div>
    <div class="blocktext">
      <p class="textpicturesheader">Lorem Ipsum is simply</p>
      <p class="textpictures">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pencil">
    <div id="containerforpencil">
      <img class="pictureone" src="https://b.radikal.ru/b39/1801/6a/339592a851eb.png">
      <img class="picturetwo" src="https://b.radikal.ru/b39/1801/6a/339592a851eb.png">
    </div>
    <div id="blocktext">
      <p class="textpicturesheader">Lorem Ipsum is simply</p>
      <p class="textpictures">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mountains">
    <div id="containerformountains">
      <img class="pictureone" src="https://b.radikal.ru/b39/1801/6a/339592a851eb.png">
      <img class="picturetwo" src="https://b.radikal.ru/b39/1801/6a/339592a851eb.png">
    </div>
    <div id="blocktext">
      <p class="textpicturesheader">Lorem Ipsum is simply</p>
      <p class="textpictures">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="clearfix"></div>
  <div id="triangle">1</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Там же написано `0px`, чему там работать-то, написано ноль — маргина и нет

Comment: я чот тоже не понял про какой маргин речь ....

Comment: Ну почему если margin-bottom: 0px; блок не прижимается к низу

Comment: @Sinevik вы не указали никакого css, который бы прижал блок к низу, а по умолчанию блоки располагаются сверху вниз. Высота section'а больше высоты всех элементов внутри него, поэтому снизу под единицей остаётся пустое пространство от section'а

Comment: И как мне правильно прижать его к низу?

Comment: А это уже вам виднее что вам надо) Хоть убирайте высоту у section'а, хоть увеличивайте высоту триангла, хоть меняйте высоты других блков, хоть добавляйте ещё блоков — вам виднее, что вы хотите, лол :)

Comment: https://image.prntscr.com/image/jQZDBWJmSl_PM5gJGeTdsg.png

Comment: margin-top добавьте, например

Comment: Первый сайт свой верстаю, хочу треугольник который внизу по цетру расположить

Comment: Ну да margin-top можно, просто это коряво получается. Думал можно как то прижать к низу. Ок спасибо

Comment: Можно и к низу через `position` и `bottom`, способов вообще много

Comment: Но вы бы лучше переформулировали вопрос и удалили избыточный код, а то в текущем виде вопрос нифига не понятен без комментариев

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно, чтобы единица к низу прижалась. Добавьте к блоку `#triangle` свойство `display: flex`, `align-items: flex-end` (это свойство как раз прижмет единицу к низу), `justify-content: center` (отцентрует единицу)

```css
#pictures {
  text-align: center;
  width: 1366px;
  height: 385px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#tv {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 193px;
}

.pictureone {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.picturetwo {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#containerfortv {
  margin-left: 70px;
  width: 111px;
  height: 112px;
  display: block;
}

#containerfortv:hover>.pictureone {
  display: none;
}

#containerfortv:hover>.picturetwo {
  display: block;
}

#pencil {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 305px;
  max-height: 300px;
  margin: 77px auto 0;
}

#containerforpencil {
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  width: 115px;
  height: 118px;
  display: block;
}

#containerforpencil:hover>.pictureone {
  display: none;
}

#containerforpencil:hover>.picturetwo {
  display: inline-block;
}

#mountains {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 305px;
  max-height: 300px;
  margin-left: 46px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#containerformountains {
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  width: 128px;
  height: 112px;
  display: block;
}

#containerformountains:hover>.pictureone {
  display: none;
}

#containerformountains:hover>.picturetwo {
  display: inline-block;
}

#clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

#triangleup {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 80px solid green;
}

#triangle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section id="pictures">
  <div id="tv">
    <div id="containerfortv">
      <img class="pictureone" src="https://b.radikal.ru/b39/1801/6a/339592a851eb.png">
      <img class="picturetwo" src="https://b.radikal.ru/b39/1801/6a/339592a851eb.png">
    </div>
    <div class="blocktext">
      <p class="textpicturesheader">Lorem Ipsum is simply</p>
      <p class="textpictures">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pencil">
    <div id="containerforpencil">
      <img class="pictureone" src="https://b.radikal.ru/b39/1801/6a/339592a851eb.png">
      <img class="picturetwo" src="https://b.radikal.ru/b39/1801/6a/339592a851eb.png">
    </div>
    <div id="blocktext">
      <p class="textpicturesheader">Lorem Ipsum is simply</p>
      <p class="textpictures">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mountains">
    <div id="containerformountains">
      <img class="pictureone" src="https://b.radikal.ru/b39/1801/6a/339592a851eb.png">
      <img class="picturetwo" src="https://b.radikal.ru/b39/1801/6a/339592a851eb.png">
    </div>
    <div id="blocktext">
      <p class="textpicturesheader">Lorem Ipsum is simply</p>
      <p class="textpictures">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="clearfix"></div>
  <div id="triangle">1</div>
</section>
```